# how to write sql query to count?

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a query for count 'noOfDistribution' within a date
and by reference. for example, there are 2 in 1/5/2013.
In addition,can someone recommend some ebook/website to learn advanced skills in
query? Thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: How can you get the count of NoOfDistribution on basis of Reference when "Reference" has NULL values.

Comment: Also what makes rows 3-6 different from 10-11? (I am assuming noOfDistribution but that also looks like you may have manually entered that as an example of what you want the query to return as opposed to an actual field in your table) If it is actually a field then you don't need to return the count, you need to return the actual noOfDistribution which you can do using distinct Why count what is already a count?

Comment: @DanDonoghue, that was I commented in my answer. I think the OP need to say if they are the same, or explain us what make theses groups different

Comment: i was simulate the export csv from peachtree that rows in 3,6 and 10-11 are entered in difference transcations, so i am asking it is possible to do it

Comment: Is there a column to determine the transaction? Ultimately the way to do this would be to select the distinct input_date, REFERENCE, noOfDistribution, TransactionID but if you don't have a transaction ID then that screws that idea.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question:

```
SELECT input_Date, REFERENCE, count(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY input_Date, REFERENCE
```

But it will result something different you pointed, since for the date 2/5/2013, it will count 6 elements for `REFERENCE` null

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like thiss....

```
select count(Input_date) over (partition by Input_date,reference),*    from table
```

By this you can find count of Particular date such as 1/5/2013 has 2 count

alternative way

```
select date,reference,count(*) from table group by date,reference
```